# Calculate the expected value

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, definite-integrals

To get the expected value of $E(X), E(Y) $ and $E(X, Y)$ given:
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 3x
$$
where $0\le x \le y \le 1.$

My solution is, first get the margin distribution:
\begin{aligned}
f_x(x) &= 3x(1-x) \\
f_y(y) &= \frac{3}{2} y^2
\end{aligned}

Then calculate the expected value: 
\begin{aligned}
E(X) &= \int_0^y 3x^2(1-x) \; dx = y^3-\frac{3}{4} y^4 \\
E(Y) &= \int_x^1 \frac{3}{2} y^3 \; dy = \frac{3}{8} (1 - x^4)
\end{aligned}

and 
\begin{aligned}
E(XY)=\int_0^y \int_x^1 xy \cdot 3x \;dy\; dx = \frac{1}{2} y^3 - \frac{3}{10} y^5
\end{aligned}

However, my calculated expected values contain variable $x$ and $y$, do I make some mistakes?

Comment: are X,Y independent?

Comment: @Alex Obviously not, as the joint density shows.

Comment: I am sorry, I miss some points, please see my last edited version.

Comment: @Did: when I wrote the comment there was no joint distribution in the post

Comment: @Alex Yes, at first I am using my middle conclusion and forget to mention the joint distribution.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: are you sure about bounds on $y$? It should be larger than $x$.

Comment: This does not appear to be a valid density.

Comment: @JohnK Why not?

Comment: Does it integrate to 1?

Comment: Yes, I got it backwards, $y$ goes from $x$ to $1$. It is better to integrate first with respect to $x$, $x=0$ to $y$, then $y$ goes $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: this is exactly what i did in my answer!

Comment: @Alex: The point I was making in my (flawed) comment is that precisely the same "method" can be used to find $E(X)$, $E(Y)$, there is no need to find the marginal densities explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[after you added the joint distribution of $X,Y$]:
to find $\mathbf{E}XY$ use 
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y}xy f(x,y)dx dy
$$
Can you handle the rest?

Comment: Thank you, but here is the point that I am confusing. Why the range of integration regarding of $y$ is $0 \rightarrow 1 $ instead of $x \rightarrow 1 $ ?

Comment: you can change the bounds of integration: either $0 <x <1 \cap x < y<1$ or $0<y<1 \cap 0<x<y$, just make sure the last integral you solve is bounded between 0 and 1

Comment: Yes, I believe my answer is wrong, but could you explain a little bit about the reason the last integral should be bounded between 0 and 1?

Comment: It's because you don't want the result to depend on either x or y

Comment: That is true, but how do you know the bounds of outside integral?

Comment: are you kidding? You gave them yourself! Third line of your question.

Comment: OK, having drawn a graph, I think I understand better...

Comment: @WeiZhong $0\le x\le y\le 1\equiv x\in [0, 1], y\in [x,1]\equiv y\in[0,1], x\in [0, y]$